# Change CCK field data type

Tags: 6, database, updating

I have a CCK field with a data type 'text', that I want to change to 'decimal'.

I have used a [hook_update_N](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!install.php/function/hook_update_N/6) and [db_change_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.pgsql.inc/function/db_change_field/6) in order to do this.

Here is an example how I tried to do it:

```
function ptm_foo_update_6005() {
  db_change_field(
    $ret,
    'content_type_',
    'field_foo_value',
    'field_foo_value',
    array(
      'type' => 'decimal(10,2)',
      'description' => 'Foo'
    )
  ); 
}
```

But when I execute the update, it gives me the following error message:

> User warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Comment: where you apply this code? means in template.php?

Comment: In a `<mymodulename>.module` file.

Comment: using mysql or pgsql ??

Comment: Using mysql, I linked the pgsql page of the documentation because the mysql one it's not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments on your question, I certainly hope you're doing this in a `.install` file and not a `.module` file.

The `$ret` variable is expected to be a reference, so you'll need to declare it before hand.

```
$ret = array();
db_change_field($ret ...);
```

Is your table name really `content_type_`?

And you may want to [look at this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.pgsql.inc/function/db_change_field/6) and stick in a couple `dsm()` calls to see what the `db_change_field()` function is actually passing to MySQL and then you could trouble shoot the query directly.